# How to render a graph from datetTime value as one of the axes value

Tags: flutter, fl-chart

Im using [fl_charts](https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart) for line chart and I have `dateTime` as X axis values but it seems `FlSpot` takes `double`  as value.

Here is my code,

```dart
LineChartBarData(
  spots: graphValues
      .map(
        (e) => FlSpot(
          e['x'],
          e['y'],//DateTime value
        ),
      )
      .toList(),
  isCurved: true,
  color: Colors.red,
  dotData: const FlDotData(
    show: false,
  ),
  barWidth: 1,
  belowBarData: BarAreaData(
    show: true,
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      colors: [
        color222E65.withOpacity(.6),
        Colors.transparent
      ],
      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    ),
  ),
),
```

How to use `DateTime` or `String` as values in this chart.

Comment: Using `DateTime` as X axis values could be ambiguous.
You can try to set some moment in time (for example on graph open) and calculate the delay between that moment and arriving DateTime values, in result getting some double value

Comment: Solved that by converting `dateTime` into `microsecondsSinceEpoch` and to `double`

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the `DateTime` into `microsecondsSinceEpoch` and into `double`. like this,

```
spots: graphValues
      .map(
        (e) => FlSpot(
          e['x'],
          (e['y'] as DateTime)
            .microsecondsSinceEpoch
            .toDouble(),
        ),
      )
      .toList(),
```